# URLWatch: Using urls.yaml from a remote URL

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to update my current urlwatch.py file with the ability to call the urls.yaml file from a remote server. I've tried to modify the urls_yaml variable with the URL I would like to use without any luck. (Generic URL is being used for the example):

```
urls_yaml = 'http://pathtourl.com/urls.yaml')
```

The standard output message is:

```
You need to create http://pathtourl.com/urls.yaml in order to use urlwatch.
        Use "urlwatch --edit" to open the file with your editor.
```

The error message is:

```
File "/Users/mattstone/Python/urlwatch-2.2/urlwatch", line 51
urls_yaml = 'http://pathtourl.com/urls.yaml')
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the above standard output, I'm confused on how I would create the yaml on a remote server when it's not installed there.

Comment: Why do you have a trailing `)` in `urls_yaml = 'http://pathtourl.com/urls.yaml')`? That is the invalid syntax that python is complaining about.

Comment: Agh! You're right, thank you.